# @IBOutlet doesn't appear on intellisense

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have had this issue since long time and assumed that `Xcode`'s update might fix this. And this issue comes in case of `@IBoutlet` only. I don't get any suggestion from intellisense. Happens every time.

[image]

As an example, `@IBAction` works fine :

[image]

Though it is not a big trouble as I can complete the rest of declaration. But has someone encountered this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can't reproduce:

[image]

However, having said that, there's an obvious solution: write your own user-defined snippet with your own abbreviation. The result will be far better than what Xcode's code completion gives you (namely nothing):

[image]

Now you can type "out" and ask for code completion, get "outlet", enter it, and presto, you've got a name and type placeholder you can fill in by tabbing to them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes , I tested it now and encountered the same issue , it's because every end of typing the syntax checker re runs and gives this error

Comment: Ok. But the question is - why does this give an error ? I tried writing @IBAction as well, it works fine.

Comment: after you end typing syntax check finds that @IB or  IBA is not unknown try to type  IBAtion. and remove n then o then I , you will get same error , I tried it know

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I accepted Matt's answer as he shared a nice workaround.